# Connection between exponential function as repeated multiplication and $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1 + \frac{1}{n})^n$ (also known as compund interest)

Tags: exponential-function, intuition, eulers-number-e

I cannot find intuitive explanation for formula $e^x = \lim_{n \to \infty} (1 + \frac{1}{n} \cdot x)^n.$ I will write down my understanding of the exponential function so you can understand the question better.

**Multiplication.**
For hole numbers, multiplication is repeated addition (subtraction). Let's say we want to find $5 \cdot 3 = x.$ We know (or better, we defined this to be) $x = 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 = 15.$

For rational numbers it's simillar but it has two steps: $\frac{3}{2}7 = x.$ Problem on the left tells us to find number $y$ such that when I add it to itself gives me $7$ then I have to add that number to zero 3 times. So $y = 3.5.$ Now, I have to find $y + y + y.$ So it's kinda back and fort game, but it still can be desribed using repeated addition (subtraction).

Finally for irrational numbers multiplication can be *approximated* with error of $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ using arithmetic in $\mathbb{Q}.$

**Exponentiation.**
Simillary as before we can do repeated multiplication. This arithmetically maybe isn't clear as before, but we can still do it (and for example doubling of something can easly be understood). Reasoning is simillar as before, just turn addition into multiplication. For example, number $7^{\frac{3}{2}} = x$ we can find as follows: find a number $y$ which multiplied by itself gives $7$ (so $y = 2.645...$). Then find $y \cdot y \cdot y.$ Thus $x = 18.520...$ For irrational exponent (base) we can  approximated it very well.

Now, we can investigate doubling of a money in hours, for example (suppose "money" can be any real number). In other words we are investigating function $f(x) = 2^x$ where $x$ is time passed in hours after 0th second.

Let's say we are starting from $2^0 = 1$ dollar. Right after 1 hour we have $2$ dollars, etc. Also 1 hour before starting moment we had $0.5$ dollars and so on. This *starting from 1* (*) will be crucial.

We can observe that if more time passes doubling become larger, of course. Take intervals of one hour and see resulting change in amount of money, for example $ \frac{2^{0} - 2^{- 1}}{1 \ \text{hour}} <  \frac{2^1 - 2^0}{1 \ \text{hour}} <\frac{2^{10} - 2^9}{1 \ \text{hour}}.$

Of course, change in money over *small* time interval (*dx*) is proportional to amount of money we already have, $2^x$ for some fixed $x.$ After hypothetical calculation we get $\frac{d}{dx}2^x \approx 0.6931 \cdot 2^x$ and simillary for any positive base, $\frac{d}{dx}b^x = kb^x.$ We want to find base $a$ such that $k = 1$ (then obviously $\frac{d}{dx}a^x = 1 \cdot a^x = a^x$). After algebraic manipulation we can find that magical number and denote it by "e": $e:= a = \lim_{n \to \infty} (1 + \frac{1}{n})^n.$

1. I am interested in intuition why this is true. Simply: why we add to starting moment, 1 (*), this fraction $\frac{1}{n}$ and then multiply it by itself $n$ times for large $n$?
2. Simillary, why we add $x$ times this fraction $\frac{1}{n}$ and then again multilpy that $n$ times (I understand $e^x = e^{1 \cdot x}$ but I do not see it clearly.

Of course if you give good argument for $e^x = \lim_{n \to \infty}(1 + \frac{x}{n})^n$ then setting $x = 1$ we get basic formula for $e.$ Please, I am looking for intuition and logic, not just algebra. Thanks!

Also, is this limit well behaved, i. e. is inequality
$|e - \lim_{n \to \infty}(1 + (\frac{1}{n + 1})^{n + 1}| < |e - \lim_{n \to \infty} ((1 + \frac{1}{n})^n|$ true?

Comment: What is your intuitive understanding of the function $x \mapsto e^x$ where $x$ can be any real number (not just an integer or rational number)? Are you comfortable with the fact that $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1 + r/n)^n = e^r$ when $r$ is a rational number? To explain why $(1+x/n)^n \to e^x$ with "intuition and logic" you have to be clear about what you mean by $e^x$.

Comment: It is hard to guess what exactly you want to be explained.

Comment: $e$ is irrational but we can find good approximation of it, some $E \in \mathbb{Q}.$ Now, if we have $E^x$ for some irrational $x$ we can also approximate it very well by some rational $X.$ I explained above that I understand rational^rational as simple arithmetic (polynomial equation)

Comment: Basically I just did (I will give here another example) $x = (\frac{1}{2})^{\frac{3}{4}} \rightarrow x^4 = (\frac{1}{2})^3 \rightarrow x^\frac{4}{3} = \frac{1}{2} \rightarrow 2x^{\frac{4}{3}} = 1$ but in words and in very clear terms

Comment: More obscure than ever. We can't read your mind.

Comment: I literally wrote this question in a way school kids can understand what multiplication and exponentiation are becase I wanted you to understand that I need sort of aritmetical explanation. Hard to explain indeed!

Comment: What $(1 + \ \text{something weird})^{\text{large number}}$ ("something weird" = $\frac{x}{n}$) has to do with property $(e^x)' = e^x$ **intuitively**?            I need explanation why slicing time into **small** pieces and then multiplying (1 + x/n) *many* times with itself is in fact $e^x$

Comment: The question, as it evolves, is getting less and less focused. I think it should be split into several small atomic questions that are clear and that *can* be answered. Voted to close. Maybe (1) Why the solution of $y'=y$ is an exponential function? (2) Why $\lim (1+x/n)^n$ is an exponential function? (3)  Why is (1) and (2) the same function? (4) Is the convergence of $(1+1/n)^n$ monotone? (5) What is the intuition behind $(1+1/n)^n$? And maybe something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1$ is not important, it's just a matter of scale. You can start with million dollars and call it "1", meaning "1 million". It's just what you have at the beginning.

Consider that you take interest $\alpha$, that is, after $1$ time unit, you would have $1+\alpha$ money, after two time-units, you would have $(1+\alpha)^2$ and so on -- if it is compounded once per time unit.

However, if you split the time unit into $n$ smaller time-intervals and take the interest more often, you will have $(1+\frac{\alpha}{n})$ money after the first $\frac{1}{n}$-th time, then $(1+\frac{\alpha}{n})^2$ after $\frac{2}{n}$ time, and so on. After the full time unit, you would have $(1 + \frac{\alpha}{n})^n$.

Algebraically speaking, if you want to prove that $(1+\frac{x}{n})^n$ is similar to $\big((1+\frac{1}{n})^n\big)^x$ (for large $n$), you can think of it as
$$
(1+\frac{x}{n})^n = (1+\frac{1}{\frac{n}{x}})^n = (1+\frac{1}{\frac{n}{x}})^{x\frac{n}{x}} = \big((1+\frac{1}{\frac{n}{x}})^{\frac{n}{x}}\big)^x \simeq \big((1 + \frac{1}{M})^M\big)^x
$$
for some large $M$.

Comment: I cannot see exatcly what cuting time in $b^x = (1 + (b - 1))^x$ have in common with property of $e^x$... Please be more detailed

Comment: @1b3b I don't see how you came to $(1+(b-1))^x$. I tried to answer questions $1$ and $2$ but probably didn't succeed :-( As others have pointed out, you are mixing too many things and I would advice you to split the question(s) into more atomic and clear questions, and go one by one.

Comment: Peter, you are right. I will once again try to give most important question of those 5 here.

So, we derived $e$ from this definition: *$e$ is solution of equation* $\frac{a^{x + h} - a^x}{h} = a^x \iff a^h - 1 = h, h \rightarrow 0$ and after some algebra and reversing $h \rightarrow 0$ of $h$ and $n \rightarrow \infty$ of $\frac{1}{n}$ we indeed get formula for compund interest. But, is there clear explanation, in words and without that few steps of algebra, why this formula works? Eplain like you are talking to kid... I will split the question. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Doubling is a relative concept.

Starting with an amount $A_0$, after 1 hour you get a total amount $A_1=2 \cdot A_0$, which gives an absolute increase $A_1-A_0 = A_0$ and a relative increase $\frac {A_1-A0}{A_0} = 1 = 100 \%$, while the new amount relative to the old is $A_1/A_0 = 2 =200 \%$.

The contribution (or one of the factors) leading to Neper logarithm seems that was on question if given an interest $x$ per year, what was amount going to be if the interest was compound every year, very quarter of year, every month, .., every minute, .. , that is $(1+x/1)^1, (1+x/4)^4, (1+x/12)^{12}, \cdots$

Comment: Yes, of course...

Answer (score 1):

$$e^m$$ is $e$ multiplied by itself $m$ times.

But $e$ is defined as

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n,$$ which turns out to exist and be the number $$1+1+\frac12+\frac1{3!}+\frac1{4!}+\cdots=2.718281828\cdots$$

Now, skipping some justifications,

$$e^m=\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\right)^m=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{nm}=\lim_{k\to\infty}\left(1+\frac mk\right)^k$$

by setting $nm=k$, so that $\dfrac1n=\dfrac mk$.

Comment: Can you please give argument I wanted without algebraic artillery? :)

Comment: @1b3b: it is unfair to call that "algebraic artillery". It boils down to the substitution $mn\leftrightarrow k$, to show how the exponent can move inside the parenthesis. As said in a comment, it is hard to understand what you are after.

Comment: Look, if you define $e$ to be solution of differential equation $\frac{d}{dx} a^x = a^x$ (as I did on purpose), then you have to *prove* $e = \lim{n \to \infty}_(1 + \frac{1}{n})^n.$ I am interested in intuitive ("wordy") proof not in algebra... Please understand me

Comment: @1b3b: I don't. You are mixing many concepts, and every explanation/question is about something different.